# How to calculate the largest prime factor of a long number efficiently?

Tags: java, primes, long-integer, prime-factoring

I tried to create a Java program to calculate the largest prime factor of any long number (in this case 600851475143). When I try to run it, the program compiles indefinitely, without producing warnings or a result. 
I understand there might be easier/more straightforward ways to solve this problem, but I'm curious on the reason why this one doesn't seem to work. I don't think the logic itself is wrong, a possible error might be my use of long variables (I have not used them often before).

I have declared some variables as long to allow them the space to be increased to a 'long' size

```
    public class LargestPrimeFactor {
    public static void main(String []args){

        long num = 600851475143L;
        long largestPrimeFactor = 0L;
        boolean flag = false;

        //Find all factors of num
        for (long i = 2L; i <= num/2; i++){

            //If a number i is a factor of num
            if((num % i) == 0){

                //Find if the factor i is a prime number (only divisible by 1 and by itself)
                //by checking whether dividing it by any number results in an integer
                for (long j = 2L; j <= i/2; j++){

                    if (i/j == 0){

                        flag = true;
                    }
                    if (!flag){

                        if (i > largestPrimeFactor){

                            largestPrimeFactor = i;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.print(largestPrimeFactor);
    }
}
```

Comment: "When I try to run it, the program compiles indefinitely, without producing warnings or a result" You don´t get any error and no compiled jar-file? Pretty hard to believe. Either you get comiler-errors, or a jar-file.

Comment: It is likely that your program takes a very long time to run. After all, it has O(n^2) running time, and your n is very large (600851475143L). You can add debug prints to see that it is actually running.

Comment: "the program compiles indefinitely" - you just didn't wait long enough. try letting it run for a day to a week. this is a very big number.

Comment: I have edited the bug and now it correctly displays i%j == 0 in the if statement

Comment: Please do not modify your question to fix the bug you found.  It makes your question meaningless.  If you feel that you must tell us the solution, add your own answer to the question, and put the bug fix into the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely, your code won't run infinitely. It's just that your code is not efficient and therefore it's taking too long to print the result. If you test with a smaller number or use an efficient code, you will get the result.

Given below is an efficient way of doing it:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long num = 600851475143L;
        long divisor = 2, largestPrimeFactor;
        while (num != 0) {
            if (num % divisor != 0) {
                divisor++;
            } else {
                largestPrimeFactor = num;
                num /= divisor;
                if (num == 1) {
                    System.out.println("The largest prime factor: " + largestPrimeFactor);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
The largest prime factor: 6857
```

Your code also has the following logical problems:

1. The variable, `flag` has been declared outside the outer loop which means that it will never be reset to `false` once it will become `true`.
2. Instead of checking `i / j == 0`, you need to check `i % j == 0`.
3. You should `break` the inner loop as soon as `i % j == 0`.
4. Also, the check for `largestPrimeFactor` needs to be moved from the inner loop to the outer one.

By the way, your test for primality is also not efficient. Instead of checking up to the half of the number, checking up to the square root of the number is sufficient. Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test for more details. Given below is an efficient code for primality test:

```
static boolean isPrime(int number) {
    boolean prime = true;
    if (number == 0 || number == 1 || number == -1)
        return false;
    for (int i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(number); i++) {
        if (number % i == 0) {
            prime = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return prime;
}
```

Comment: I do want to point out however that I don't think it's correct to put   i <= Math.sqrt(num) in the first for loop. Mathematically speaking, we know that when checking if i is prime, we only need to check until sqrt(i) for possible factors. However when looking for all factors of num we cannot stop before num/2. A prime factor is not always less than the number's square root.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't specifically address all the issues in your algorithm but it can provide some guidance. Your given number should factor very quickly as its prime factors are very close in magnitude.  That makes it faster because the target number reduces faster as other factors are found.

Consider the following examples.  The first value is yours, the next is a much larger one, and the third is the smallest (and last for a reason).

The output looks like the following: In fact, this is your number.  The `adding` part is a new factor, the `continuing` part is what is left after division by that factor and what is subject to further factorization.  The values in brackets are the found factors for the given number.

```
Checking: 600851475143
Adding 71, continuing with 8462696833
Adding 839, continuing with 10086647
Adding 1471, continuing with 6857
Adding 6857, continuing with 1
[71, 839, 1471, 6857]
```

The result is that the first two numbers factor very quickly. The third will take a long time.  That is because it is prime and using this method I would have to generate all primes up to that value to verify that fact.  So it isn't the size that is the only factor (pun intended) it is the relative magnitude of the prime factors.

Here is the test procedure.

```
        for (long test : new long[] { 600851475143L,
                14385829455476874L,  300851475157L }) {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Checking: " + test);
            List<Long> factors = findFactors(test);
            System.out.println(factors);
        }
    
    static private int lastReturnedPrimeIdx = 0;
    static private List<Long> primes = new ArrayList<>(
            List.of(2L, 3L));
    
   // find all prime factors in a supplied number.
    public static List<Long> findFactors(long n) {
        List<Long> factors = new ArrayList<>();
        lastReturnedPrimeIdx = 0;
        while (n > 1) {
            long p = nextPrime();
            while (n % p == 0) {
                factors.add(p);
                n /= p;
                System.out.println("Adding " + p
                        + ", continuing with " + n);
            }
        }
        return factors;
    }

    // Get the next prime. This memoizes the primes as they are computed.
    // Future tests on the same run can thus take advantage of the cached values.
    // Prime are computed in bulk.
    private static long nextPrime() {
        if (lastReturnedPrimeIdx < primes.size()) {
            return primes.get(lastReturnedPrimeIdx++);
        }

        // start where the it left off last time.
        long candidate = primes
                .get(lastReturnedPrimeIdx - 1);
        long max = primes.size() + 1_000; // generate 1000 more primes.

        outer:
        while (primes.size() < max) {
            candidate += 2;
            long bound = (long)Math.sqrt(candidate);
            for (int i = 0; i < primes.size(); i++) {
                long p = primes.get(i);
                if (candidate % p == 0 ) {
                    continue outer;
                }
                if (p > bound) {
                    break;
                }
                
            }
            primes.add(candidate);
        }
        return (primes.get(lastReturnedPrimeIdx++));
    }
}
```

One final note:  I recommend you compute future candidate primes by:

1. Only dividing candidates by already found primes.
2. Checking only odd candidates after 2.
3. Only check `primes` up to the square root of the candidate.

Another option is the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you program compiles fine but is caught in an infinite (or very long) loop
If you put `System.out.println("program started");` at the start of your `main` method you will probably see it displayed.

Also if you lower `long num` you will see your method finishing.

---

EDIT:
You have two nested for loops.
The first one executes num/2 times and the other one (num/2)/2.

If I'm not wrong, that means it will loop (num^2)/8 times. Which for `long num = 600851475143L;` is a lot. Hence your app is stuck iterating more than `4.51 × 10^22` times

Comment: Is this an **answer** or just a **guess**?

Comment: Well that is the behavior on my machine. Also it is the explanation that makes most sense to me. So it's a theory that OP should test on their code.

Answer (score 0):

Finding factors is a very compute intensive operation.

Therefore, it is normal for the computer to take a very long time while doing such calculations.

The running time of the calculation can be reduced by reducing the number of iterations.

For example, iterations on all the even numbers that are greater than 2 can be avoided, as those cannot be primes.

Here is the link to working code found on Github:

https://gist.github.com/joseporiol/8559440