# Project Euler #3 in Java; program not outputting result

Tags: java, primes

I am trying solve problem 3 in Project Euler:

> The prime factors of 13195 are 5, 7, 13 and 29.
>
> What is the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143 ?

This is my code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        long max = 600851475143L;
        ArrayList<Long> primes = new ArrayList<>();
        primes.add((long) 2);
        boolean prime = true;
        for (long i = 3; i <= max; i += 2){
            for (long j = 3; j < Math.sqrt(i); j++){
                if (i % j == 0){
                    prime = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (prime) primes.add(i);
            else prime = true;
        }
        for (int i = primes.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--){
            if (max % primes.get(i) == 0){
                System.out.println(primes.get(i));
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code is not outputting anything, it just gives me a blank screen. Please do not solve the problem for me, just tell me what the bug is that is preventing it from outputting anything.

Comment: Does the program ever stop running? If it doesn't, that could mean the part of the program that generates primes takes too long.

Comment: @Nosrep It does not, in fact, ever stop. I didn't notice that.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59809835/how-to-calculate-the-largest-prime-factor-of-a-long-number-efficiently/59810637#59810637 help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are wasting time calculating all the primes when you don't have too.

- When you find the first prime, try reducing `max` by that prime until it is not longer divisible.
- Then continue finding the next prime.
- and reducing max by factoring out that prime.
- each time check to see if max is equal to the current prime.  If so, you are done.

Assuming you are finding primes correctly (which I believe you are) consider the following:

```
primes = 2,3,5,7,11,13
max = 99

is 99 divisible by 2 - no, try next prime.
is 99 divisible y  3 -  yes
max = 33
is 33 divisble by 3  - yes 
max = 11
is 11 divisible by 3 - no
by 5 - no
by 7 - no
by 11 - hey, max is a prime! And it must be the largest because
it can't be reduced anymore.
```

And if you want, when finding each prime factor of max, save it in a list.

Then multiply all the values in the list to see if the product == max.

Here is your code

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        long max = 600851475143L;
          // right here, reduce max by current prime (which starts at 2)

        for (long i = 3; i <= max; i += 2){
            boolean prime = true;
            for (long j = 3; j < Math.sqrt(i); j++){
                if (i % j == 0){
                    prime = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (prime)  {
            // right here, reduce max by current prime

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't completely understand your solution. Why doesn't that output the lowest prime?

Comment: Note.  If  max has  large primes as factors.  It will take a long time.  If max is a prime.  It will take a significantly longer time.

Comment: But I still need a more efficient algorithm to get that initial list of primes, right? As pointed out in the comments to the other answer, the algorithm I'm using now will take 7 days.

Comment: You need a more efficient algorithm.  But not to necessarily compute primes.  That is not the long pole in tent.  Did you try my suggestion(s)?

Comment: I'm sorry, I hope I'm not being obtuse, but don't I first need a list of primes before I can use your method?

Comment: No, you need to compute the primes, but you don't even need to save them. Just use them as they are computed to reduce max by continued division.  Then get the next prime and do the same.  See the updated answer.

Comment: That worked, thanks, but I can't quite understand why.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure your program is completing? Iadded the following code below and it looks like the first for loop is going to take a long time to complete, which may be why you aren't seeing any output. To see your progress, try adding in a print statement like below:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        long max = 600851475143L;
        ArrayList<Long> primes = new ArrayList<Long>();
        primes.add((long) 2);
        boolean prime = true;
        for (long i = 3; i <= max; i += 2){
            if(i % 1000005 == 0)
                System.out.println("i = " + i);
            for (long j = 3; j < Math.sqrt(i); j++){
                if (i % j == 0){
                    prime = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (prime) primes.add(i);
            else prime = true;
        }
        for (int i = primes.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--){
            if (max % primes.get(i) == 0){
                System.out.println(primes.get(i));
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not the problem.

Comment: That may not be the whole problem, but it is one of them. What do you think the bigger problem is?

Comment: It takes too long to find all those primes.  Look at my answer and see what you think?

Comment: Also, I believe the OP should have only been iterating form 1 to sqrt(max) since any subsequent quotient would have been found. So you were definitely onto something.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, if I let it run long enough it will output a result, it will just take a very long time, correct?

Comment: @ap yes, if we assume it calculates 1000 numbers per millisecond, it will take almost 7 days

Comment: The  number of primes less than `N` is about `N/log(N)` where `log` is the natural log.  So for `max = 600851475143` you will need to calculate and store about `22,153,972,243` values.  So you (@ap) need to approach it from a different angle as I have already suggested.